# Delphi & C++ POS communication with DLL

Tags: c++, delphi

I'm trying to make my fiscal printer work without "driver" which is written in c++, and communicate with files. I want to avoid that and to make direct communication using dll file for fiscal printer.

After I send command "F0"(printer status), in c++ app answer is:
060052000001000000018400000003AE5145202020524D20333330393833322020202031352E30382E323031332031343A3330

After I send command "F0"(printer status), in delphi app answer is:
䁘

c++ code:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) char* __stdcall TransmitPrinterCommand(int IPCom, char* Port, int BaudRateNr, char* Command);
cprt = TransmitPrinterCommand(0, cp.c_str(), StrToInt(Baud), EditCommand->Text.c_str());

if (cprt.Length() == 2)
    { ... error
```

delphi code:

```
function TransmitPrinterCommand(IPCom:integer; Port:AnsiString; BaudRateNr:integer; Command:AnsiString):WideChar;
     stdcall; external 'QPrintFM.dll';
...
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  cprt:WideChar;
begin
  cprt:=TransmitPrinterCommand(0,AnsiString('COM2'), 9600, AnsiString(txtKomanda.Text));
  txtRez.Text:=cprt;
end;
```

**EDIT 3**
As Re0sless suggested I changed code in:

```
function TransmitPrinterCommand(IPCom:integer; Port:AnsiString; BaudRateNr:integer; Command:AnsiString):PAnsiChar;
stdcall; external 'QPrintFM.dll';

cprt:=TransmitPrinterCommand(0,AnsiString('COM2'), 9600, AnsiString(txtKomanda.Text))
```

Now all works wine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know that the answer is hex data and in this case it means:
??R?????????????QE   RM 3309832    15.08.2013 14:30

Comment: Try swapping your `AnsiString` with `PAnsiChar` in `TransmitPrinterCommand` see here for c++ to Delphi mappings http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Delphi_to_C%2B%2B_types_mapping

Comment: Once again I have jumped from my chair! Thanks, Re0sless!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Delphi translation of the C++ function is wrong. You cannot use managed Delphi strings across a DLL boundary. The Delphi equivalent of a char*, pointer to null-terminated array of char is PAnsiChar.

You need:

```
function TransmitPrinterCommand(
  IPCom: Integer; 
  Port: PAnsiChar; 
  BaudRateNr: Integer; 
  Command: PAnsiChar
): PAnsiChar; stdcall; external 'QPrintFM.dll';
```

Call it like this:

```
cprt := TransmitPrinterCommand(
  0,
  'COM2', 
  9600,
  PAnsiChar(AnsiString(txtKomanda.Text))
);
```

I'm not sure what the protocol is for deallocating the return value of the function. That's something that you should check carefully. There's no way that you can deallocate it, so either the DLL exports a deallocator, or the memory is statically allocated.

Comment: I have removed second question, as you sugessted.
Now when I have correct response from printer, I can separate errors (ie. 06) and success (>2 characters).
Thanks, guys!